# The integral $\int\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

Is $$\int\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}dx$$ the same as the integral of $$\sec x+\tan x$$ (since $1/\cos x = \sec x$ and $\sin x/\cos x = \tan x$)?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

The alternate form you suggest is of course correct. But for integrating, we can also profitably work with the expression as given. Multiply "top" and "bottom" by $1-\sin x$. So we want 
$$\int \frac{\cos x\,dx}{1-\sin x}.$$
Now with or without the substitution $u=1-\sin x$, we arrive at $-\ln(1-\sin x)+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Of course
$$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\sec x+\tan x$$
Now observe that
$$\int \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}dx=\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx+\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx$$
For the first integral 
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x}dx$$
This and the second integral are straighforward

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: @JadenM.: It is indeed a  complete answer. +1